# How can I iterate a multi-dimensional array with Jade template lang

Tags: node.js, pug

I'm wondering if it is possible to iterate a multi-dimensional array, in Node.js I'm returning an array that has an object inside of it, and I'm putting it into an array so that I can push to it, but when it is all done pushing, I'm left with something like

```
[ [
   {
     stuff: stuff
   }
  ],
  [ 
   { 
    stuff: stuff
   }
  ]
]
```

I tried

```
each item in items
  p= item
```

which returns `[object Object]`

When I try

```
each item in items
  p= item.invdescription
```

I get an error, any idea how I can do such a thing with Jade? Thanks!

Basically:

```
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i += 1) {
  p= items[0][i].invdescription
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if `items` is having the value

```
[ [
   {
     stuff: stuff
   }
  ],
  [ 
   { 
    stuff: stuff
   }
  ]
]
```

then you can iterate over the `stuff` values in jade via

```
each item in items
     p #{item[0].stuff}
```

Comment: Why using [0] after item ? Isn't item already indexing each element of 'items' ?

Comment: Ah yes that's because it's an array of array of object, I did not see the '[ ['